# How to load MobileSubstrate extension with root permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

Below is contents of filter file.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Filter</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Executables</key>
        <array>
            <string>installd</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>SupportsRoot</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The extension was loaded with mobile permission.

How to load it with root permission?

Comment: As far as I know, MobileSubstrate inserts your dylib in an existing process, therefore the extension is loaded with that process' permissions... Not sure there's a way to change that

Comment: Have a look at here, it has been answered once:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837663/root-privileges-for-mobile-substrate-tweak